# gcc -lpthread not working

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, gcc, operating-system

I have ubuntu 11 installed in my system. I have a c program that uses the pthread library. 
I get the error `Undefined reference to sem_wait()` even if I have compiled with the flag `-lpthread`.

for example:

```
gcc -lpthread prog.c
```

The program works fine on other ubuntu installations.

Comment: can you try compiling something else with pthread calls?

Comment: The linking order matters. Libraries have to come at the end only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
gcc -pthread
```

instead of `-lpthread`.  The difference is significant, I believe.  The latter is linking against `libpthread`, the former is linking against libpthread and a bunch of other things, too!

`sem_wait` is part of librt, so you could just as well use `gcc -lrt`, but `-pthread` does this for you (and everything else as well!).