# Eclipse setting for including paths

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to compile the Dlib library in Eclipse, but have an error in linking.
According to: http://dlib.net/compile.html I have to include the path containing the dlib folder (that's what I did) and include the source file in my project: dlib/all/source.cpp.

I keep on getting the following error:
../source.cpp:7:41: fatal error: ../base64/base64_kernel_1.cpp: No such file or directory
This is a line from the source.cpp file. The directory looks like: 
/usr/include/dlib-18.6/dlib/base64, If I add that path in my library I get the next error:
In function `dlib::threads_kernel_shared_helpers::thread_starter(void*)':
/usr/include/dlib-18.6/dlib/base64/../threads/threads_kernel_2.cpp:37: undefined reference to`pthread_detach'

Do I have to keep adding paths after each error?
Why doesn't Eclipse just add all subpaths of my /usr/include/dlib-18.6/ (that's the path containing dlib and the it's the path I added)?

Comment: Do you hav e an installed version of `dlib`, or do you try to build it as CTD C++ project? Looks you're missing `-lpthread`/`-pthread` linking options primarily!

Comment: not installed, just try to build it as Eclipse C++ project

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends a bit, on how you had setup your particular toolchain, to build your main/dlib project.

Building using e.g. GCC 4.8 (and using the `-std=c++11` option) might require to specify the [`-pthread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127797/gcc-significance-of-pthread-flag-when-compiling) option on linking stage, other environments might want to link against [`-lpthread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264701/gcc-lpthread-not-working).

Comment: I did set it up with GCC4.8 and -std=C++11, what did you make this comment?

Comment: @user3116431 (You're right maybe that fits better a comment than an answer!) `dlib` compiled using all the same conditions?